# Couldn't find package "react-scrips@4.0.1" required by "main@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I can't install any packages

```
yarn install v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "react-scrips@4.0.1" required by "main@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried `npm config delete registry` and delete node_modules and re-install everything with yarn but they didn't work.

also, my editor shows a list of available versions of other packages but no 'react-scripts'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its `react-scripts` not 'scrips'. You are most probably making typo.

Comment: thank you, I will accept these answer after 12 minutes :)